# Proper way to get label from system.xml

Tags: magento2, system.xml

I have a form in the store -> configuration what I've created in my `system.xml`.

Before save I want to validate it. When an error happens, I want to inform the user what field was not valid.

How can I read out the label of the field from a `Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value` in the `beforeSave` method?

Now I can read out like this:

```
$label = $this->getData('field_config')['label'];
```

But is this the proper way to get the label? Isn't there a method or cleaner way to do it?

Comment: What kind of validation you required ? What kind of input you are using?

Comment: I am using custom `frontend_model` to show 2 fields. This 2 fields are in one row, I have a set of theese. I need to get a name and a hexa color for css. When I validate in the `backend_model`, I want to show what was the label of the bad value(s).